# Why I can't parse Options with using Apache CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, numberformatexception

My problem is when I create `Options` instance, and set there data, it can't read a value from my static field `"ITEM_COUNT"`. Can't understand what problem is this?

```
public class Main {

    public static final String ITEM_COUNT = "100";

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {


        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption(ITEM_COUNT, true, "The number of items being simulated" );

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args );

// there I have NumberFormatException:null, the value from ITEM_COUNT is null

        Integer item_count = Integer.valueOf(cmd.getOptionValue(ITEM_COUNT)); 

        Runner mockServer = new Runner();
        mockServer.initialize(item_count);
        mockServer.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it strange to call the option `100`? Also which command line did you use to start the program?

Comment: @Henry Nope, the `String` value need for other logic, but the miss isn't in it. The problem is right here. Value is null, but not `100` as I expect. I run with IDE, try with Command Line, but can't too

Comment: `100` is the name of the option. The value would be whatever you pass in on the command line. You would use something like `--100=42` to get the value 42.

Comment: @Henry Oh, I thought about that.. Never used this library before. I just need to compile this class through `java Main.class 100`?

Comment: No, `java Main.class --100=100` if you want to use a value of 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run **Run -> Edit Configuration -> Program arguments ->** *-name_of_arg* *value_of_arg*.